# case insensitive multiple conditions checking for input

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've got written a calculator on python 3 in pycharm edu. The part of the code is here:

```
def again():
    calc_again = input('''
Repeat?
''')
#disagreements = frozenset('N'or 'No' or 'Not')
#agreements = frozenset('Y' or 'Yes' or 'Ya')
    if (calc_again.upper()=='Y' or calc_again.upper()=='Yes' or calc_again.upper()=='Ya'):
        calc()
    elif (calc_again=='N' or calc_again=="No" or calc_again=='Not'):
        print('Exit')
        again()
    else:
        print('Type y/n')
```

The problem appears when I'm trying to input any other condition except `Y` and `N`, it just doesn't respond fine, and I doubt it's case insensitive as well.

I was trying to use:

```
if calc_again.upper() in agreements:
    do..
```

but it just gives me the same result.

Can somebody fix it and explain?
Also, may be it's better to use "`while True`" instead of "`again()`" (11 str)?

UPD
with last changes it looks like

---

```
def again():    
    possible_conditions = frozenset(['y', 'yes', 'ya', 'n', 'no', 'not'])
    calc_again = input('Go again?')
    agreements = frozenset(['y', 'yes', 'ya'])
    if calc_again.lower() in possible_conditions:
        if calc_again.lower() in agreements:
            calc()
        else:
            print('bye')
            exit()
    else:
        print('choose y or n')
        again()
```

Comment: `calc_again.upper()` will never be equal to `'Yes'`, because `'Yes'` is not upper case.

Comment: so I should have listed every condition only upper-cased and then it should work?

Comment: What do you see when your input is something not equal to 'Y' and 'N'?

Comment: I’ve already finished with that part of code, and as well I’ve added while loop thing so now it works fine. Just didn’t know, as you said, that ‘Yes’ doesn’t work with ‘upper() function.

Comment: Before it just asked me to input needed condition again with ‘go again?’ question. Thanks a lot for ur help and sorry for late reply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you are checking UPPER version of calc_again string. So you will have always uppercase letters in calc_again.upper(). To fix your code, just make your list of possible cases upper.

```
if (calc_again.upper()=='Y' or calc_again.upper()=='YES' or calc_again.upper()=='YA'):
        calc()
    elif (calc_again=='N' or calc_again=="NO" or calc_again=='NOT'):
        print('Exit')
        again()
    else:
        print('Type y/n')
```

Also, I think you have to put your if statements in while loop, because it have to be executed always depending on user inputs.